# Is there a way to pass an argument by reference in an async asmx web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, asynchronous

I have some asmx web services, some of which take arguments by reference. Now I'm using these web services in a silverlight application and have found that silverlight only lets me work with asmx web services asynchronously, and because of, will no longer let me pass something by reference. Is there a way to pass reference arguments on asynchronous calls to asmx web services?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create simple `struct` out of your `ref` parameters and use it in `Silverlight` ? You can add wrapper methods around your existing methods, just returning the `structs`.

Hope this helps...